# Keeping address space size to 4 GB in 64 bit

Tags: c, linux, 64-bit, x86

I want to keep some applications to run with a 4 GB address space within a 64 bit OS running on a 64 bit processor (x86 xeon, 8 core). I know there is an option to compile with -m32 option, but at this moment the computer I'm working with, doesn't have the required support for compiling with -m32, so I can't use it, neither I can install anything on that computer as I don't have any rights.

Now my question is if there is any possibility to restrict address space to 4 GB. Please don't ask me why I want to do so, just tell me how if that is possible. Thanks.

Comment: Let me guess: You have some code you can't/won't touch which stores pointers in int-handles?

Comment: Unclear question: 1) do you want to restrict your program to use only linear addresses from 0..4GB, or 2) do you want to restrict the total size of the program's address space to 4GB, regardless of where it is placed?

Comment: @zvrba, linear addresses from 0 to 4GB. Do you think ulimit -v would be enough for that?

Comment: @Luther. Not exactly, but due to something a little bit similar.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: Well, ulimit -v/setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS) limits how much address space the process may use, but there is not guarantee that the numerical value of the addresses will be smaller than the limit.

Comment: @Janneb - Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @MetallicPriest: Beyond actually fixing your code to be 64-bit clean, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ulimit/setrlimit mechanism, accessible in bash via ulimit, can do this with minor drawbacks.

```
ulimit -v 4000000
```

should limit the memory available to the current process group to 4 GB.

However, it limits the total *size* of your address space mappings, and does not limit your mappings' offset
- you still may have pointers larger than 2^32.

Comment: Thanks Thiton. What are the drawbacks, assuming my application is not hungry for too much memory and can easily do with 4 GB?

Comment: The one I know: You can't control the memory allocation precisely because it is limited to the process group. And there might be others, at least I have heard so in hearsay.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [`setrlimit`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) to impose a virtual memory limit on the process during its initialization, via the `RLIMIT_AS` attribute. I have used `setrlimit` to *increase* resource allocations to a user space process before, but I don't see why it wouldn't work in the other direction as well.

Comment: Don't see why it was allowed to  *increase* resource allocations... Setrlimit works only to decrease allowed resources. Or you was a superuser?

Comment: Yes, in a supervisory user space application run with root permissions.